# Convert "2012-04-10T15:57:51.013" to Date javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How i can convert this format "2012-04-10T15:57:51.013" to Date javascript object with Jquery or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple JavaScript Date:

```
var x = '2012-04-10T15:57:51.013';
var dateObject = new Date(x);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cunz7/)

May be not work for all browsers. Better would be use **[datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)**

Comment: @user1575030 ya, it works in FF, so to avoid these use datejs.